# Oracle inner join two select queries with columns first in second

Tags: oracle, inner-join

I am trying to join two select queries where a column from the first query is used as value in the second query. Here's what the query looks like -

```
SELECT q1.a, q1.b, q2.a, q2.b FROM
 (SELECT
    func(sysdate, someDate) as a, 
    col2 as b,
    rownum AS r
     FROM DUAL) q1
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT
    func(q1.a, someDate) as a,
    col4 as b,
    rownum AS r
    FROM DUAL) q2
USING (r)
```

As you can see the problem is  `func(q1.a, someDate)` . It is a function that takes the value of the column 'a' from 'q1' (which is also a date).

The data with the same query looks like

> 80.05     2015-11-16 17:26:00        80.05        2015-11-16 17:26:00     1

*Note: Col2 and Col4 are also functions where col4 refers to col2 value. I just didn't want to type it here because that would look confusing. This query will be chained up to 8 more selects.*

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I typed this on a phone because it just wouldnt get past the proxy.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `dual` only returns one row, so why the `JOIN` using `r`?

Comment: How else would you have joined that?

Comment: It does not help with your current problem, but a `CROSS JOIN` allows to join all rows of one table with all rows of another table. You got the answer to your current question by Mike, but I guess that there is a much better solution to the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like something along the lines of the query below is what you're after:

```
WITH q1 AS 
( SELECT func(sysdate, someDate) as a, 
         col2 as b,
         rownum AS r
    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT q1.a, 
       q1.b, 
       func(q1.a, someDate) as a,
       col4 as b
 FROM q1
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `a` and `b` as column aliases for the function return value and `col4`, if the result of the outer query will also have columns `a` and `b` from the subquery. The latter columns will be automatically renamed by Oracle to `a_1` and `b_1` - which will lead to bugs sooner or later.

Comment: That works perfectly and for the question asked that is the answer. I was wondering if there is a way to chain this. What I am trying to do is read the last 10 dates and and values. What I have is last two. That custom function extracts the last date and value. Obviously I can create a new function that does this but I want to see if I can re-use this existing one.